# iOS fixed width dynamic height scrollview with autolayout in xib

Tags: uiscrollview, autolayout, constraints

I was creating a scrollview contains an image view and a dynamic height label,

here's my hierarchy in xib file:

-> view (originally existed view when xib file created )

--> scroll view

---> content view

----> image + label (dynamic height depend on its content)

I set the content view's height depend on the label's height

,and then set the scroll view's content size(scrollable area) to the content view's frame size

I expect the content view and the scroll view both has equal width to the top view

(top view's width is flexible when device got rotated, and also are the content view & scroll view's)

and only the vertical direction is scrollable.

yet I totally have no idea dealing with the autolayout,

once I set the content view's constraints to the top view, the scrolling becomes disable,

but after I remove all constraints the content view'd be scrolled like a bouncing block...

(sorry for not providing any picture but only description for my question due to low reputation)

been mad about this for a whole day

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @HusseinB nah... doing it with storyboard without this problem now